# different color line per category chartit django 1.6

Tags: python, django, charts, highcharts, colors

I am creating a loop of charts and I would like to keep specified color for each category so in every chart the same category is always represented by same color, but I am completly lost. Any help, thanks

```
            cht = Chart(
                        datasource = ventasdata, 
                        series_options = 
                            [{'options':{'type': 'line','stacking': False, 'colors': ['#00cc00', '#ff5050','#00cc00']}, # Para area cambiar a 'type': 'area'
                                'terms':{
                                    'mes': [
                                        # 'cantidad_total_mes_2015',
                                        'cantidad_acumulado_2015'],
                                    'mes_2014': [
                                        # 'cantidad_total_mes_2014',
                                        'cantidad_acumulado_2014'],
                                    'mes_2016': [
                                        # 'cantidad_total_mes_2016',
                                        'cantidad_acumulado_2016']
                                        }}],
                        chart_options = 
                            # {'colors': ['#00cc00','#ff5050','#3333ff'], 'title': {
                            {'mes': {
                                'color': '#00cc00'},
                            'cantidad_acumulado_2014': {
                                'color': ['#ff5050']},
                            'cantidad_acumulado_2016': {
                                'color': ['#3333ff']},
                            'terms':{
                                # 'colors': ['#00cc00','#ff5050','#3333ff']},
                                'colors': [['#00cc00'],'#ff5050','#3333ff']},
                            'title': {
                            # {'title': {
                                'text': titulo},
                                'xAxis': {
                                    'title': {'text': 'MES'}}},
                        x_sortf_mapf_mts = (None, monthname, False))
                    return cht
```

Comment: Do you use any specific wrapper/plugin for Highcharts? In Highcharts, it should be done like this: http://jsfiddle.net/77qfv3at/8/ Note that order of categories must be the same to make this by defaults.

Comment: Thanks for your comment Pawel. I am using [Chartit ](http://chartit.shutupandship.com/). When creating charts inside a for loop, each category gets the default colors radomly, which makes a difficult interpretation of the charts.

Comment: I'm not familiar with chartit, so it is hard for me to say why those colors are random. I would try to set color for each of the points manually, before rendering chart.